# Proving a non-isolated singularity is an essential singularity

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Here stated more rigorously,

Let $\{p_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}} $ be the set of singularity of an analytic function $f(z)$ on a bounded domain $U\backslash{\{p_n\}}$. We know that $p_n$ has at least a limit point (By Bolzano Weierstrass). Call one of the limit point $p$. Then $p$ is an essential singularity of $f(z)$.

**Here's my attempt Proof**

Define $F(z)=(z-p)^N f(z)$ for the sake of contradiction, we assume that $p$ is not an essential singularity of $f$, ie. there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\lim_{z\to p} (z-p)^N f(z)$ exists which I am going to call it $\alpha _0$.

-$F(z)$ has poles at $z\in\{p_n\}\backslash p$

So for all $M\in\mathbb{N}$: $$\lim_{z\to p_M}F(z)=\mathrm{Diverges}$$
At this point, I guess I could conclude that $${\underbrace{\lim_{M\to \infty}\lim_{z\to p_M}F(z)}_{=\lim_{z\to p}F(z)}}={\underbrace{\lim_{M\to \infty}\mathrm{Diverges}}_{\mathrm{True \, for \, all }\, M\in \mathbb{N} }}=\mathrm{Divergent}$$
And $\lim_{z\to p}F(z)=$ Divergent but also equal to $\alpha_0$ which is a contradiction.
This finishes the proof

But I can seem to see that if this is intuitively true: ${\underbrace{\lim_{M\to \infty}\mathrm{Diverges}}_{\mathrm{True \, for \, all }\, M\in \mathbb{N} }}=\mathrm{Divergent}$.

Ie. does limit preserve divergence?

Comment: “Limit point of poles is a non isolated essential singularity “ This is a standard theorem in texts.

Comment: And I'm trying to prove this theorem, what's your point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is correct. As $F$ has finite limit at $p$ it must be bounded in a nbd of $p$, by the definition of limit point there is some $p_M$ there at which $F$ is bounded, which finishes the proof

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I may have been too persistent on the word divergence, if I consider the map $\phi:\text{Divergent}\mapsto 1$ being true for all $n$, This would just be $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(p_n)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\text{Divergent}=\lim_{n\to \infty}1 =1=\text{Divergent}$.

This concludes the proof